# Javascript minification when eclipse builds my Java EE application?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, yui

I am having Java EE application in which I was using ANT in order to do all my tasks. For the minification of JavaScript I was using YUI Compressor and its ANT plugin and used to compress my files during build. Now my problem is that I want to use the default eclipse build and achieve the same result. I want to know that whether is it possible to minify the JavaScript used in my project during the time eclipse builds my project or may be when it creates a war archive ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm personnaly using ant, together with Google's closure compiler, to concatenate and minify all my CSS and javascript file when I'm building my Java EE application.

The steps are

- concatenate all css files in one
- concatenate  all the js files
- apply minification on the js concatenated file

I have something like this :

```
<target name="minify-m3" depends="init">
    <description>build the compacted/minified version </description>
    <echo>Concatenating the css...</echo>
    <concat destfile="${somevar.dir}/pmc.concat.css">
        <fileset dir="${somevar.dir}/skins/contrast">
           <filename name="*.css"/>
           <not><filename name="**/pmc.concat.css"/></not>
      </fileset>
    </concat>

    <echo>Concatenating javascript...</echo>
    <concat destfile="${somevar.dir}/pmc.concat.js">
        <!-- Attention : ensure there is no  Unicode BOM in the files -->
        <!-- attention : keep js files in order! -->
        <filelist dir="src/webapp/m3">
            <file name="graphic_utils.js" />
            <file name="Rect.js" />
            ...
        </filelist>
    </concat>

    <echo>Concatenating using the Closure Compiler...</echo>
    <jscomp compilationLevel="simple" warning="quiet" debug="false" output="${somevar.dir}/pmc.min.js">
        <sources dir="src/webapp/m3">
            <file name="pmc.concat.js" />
        </sources>
    </jscomp>
    <echo>Finished</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: I too have an ant script for the above purpose. But I feel that is there any way in Eclipse build tool itself where I can specify what to do or any other kind of configuration that would help me so that this process could be a part of the war creation(as in before war creation this is done). Is there some internal mechanism in eclipse?

Comment: I don't think so. This isn't really in the realm of Eclipse.

Comment: Note that with each html page normally requiring different css and js files, it would be a little complex for Eclipse to guess what to do.

Comment: Actually I have a custom set of files common to each page. So thought if this could be done in anyways. But from your answer should I conclude that there is no direct way of doing this ? :)

Comment: You should conclude that **I** don't know a direct way. Maybe somebody will provide a better answer. I you think my answer isn't really an useful answer (I'm not sure after your comments), tell it and I'll remove it.

Comment: Not at all. This is useful since I have someone discussing with me about the above. I am really thankful. Was just trying to reconfirm. Because I wanted to know whether such option exists or not.The script you mentioned is helpful too. I guess the best part would be to keep an external script which can be called before we deploy a war right ? (I gave a vote up to prove my point :))

Comment: The reason why I keep it in ant and Eclipse is that I use the facilities provided (variables, or inter-projects links, for example) for the building of my application (many targets, many variables depending on the users and their OS, specific targets to launch debug or deploy, etc.). This is usually the same reasons as to build your application from Eclipse.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Pretty convincing though.Thanks a lot for explaining. I ll keep it externally for some tasks that are really critical before deployment.Thanks!! :) You get the correct answer! :)

Comment: How are you minifying css files?